# Oracle case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case-statement

```
If I have 2 tables:

table1-QITEM
ITEMNAME                              QTYONHAND
---------------------------------------------
boots-snakeproof                      100
camel saddle                          100
compass                               100
elephant polo stick                   100
exploring in 10 easy lessons          100
geo positioning system                100
hammock                               100
hat-polar explorer                    100
how to win foreign friends            100
map case                              100
map measure                           100
pith helmet                           100
pocket knife-avon                     100
pocket knife-nile                     100
safari chair                          100
safari cooking kit                    100
sextant                               100
stetson                               100
tent-2 person                         100
tent-8 person                         100


table2-QDEL
DELNO     DELQTY   ITEMNAME                         SPL 
-------------------------------------------------------
51        50       pocket knife-nile                102
52        10       pocket knife-nile                105
53        10       pocket knife-nile                105
54        10       pocket knife-nile                105
55        10       pocket knife-nile                105
56        10       pocket knife-nile                105
57        50       compass                          101
58        10       geo positioning system           101
59        10       map measure                      101
60        25       map case                         101
61        2        sextant                          101
62        1        sextant                          105
63        20       compass                          103
64        1        geo positioning system           103
65        15       map measure                      103
66        1        sextant                          103
67        5        sextant                          102
68        3        sextant                          104
69        5        boots-snakeproof                 105
70        15       pith helmet                      105
71        1        pith helmet                      101
72        1        pith helmet                      102
73        1        pith helmet                      103
74        1        pith helmet                      104
75        5        pith helmet                      105
76        5        pith helmet                      105
77        5        pith helmet                      105
78        5        pith helmet                      105
79        5        pith helmet                      105
80        10       pocket knife-nile                102
81        1        compass                          102
82        1        geo positioning system           102
83        10       map measure                      102
84        5        map case                         102
85        5        compass                          102
86        5        pocket knife-avon                102
87        5        tent-2 person                    102
88        2        tent-8 person                    102
89        5        exploring in 10 easy lessons     102
90        5        how to win foreign friends       102
91        10       exploring in 10 easy lessons     102
92        10       how to win foreign friends       102
93        2        exploring in 10 easy lessons     102
94        2        how to win foreign friends       102
95        5        compass                          105
96        2        boots-snakeproof                 105
97        20       pith helmet                      106
98        20       pocket knife-nile                106
99        1        sextant                          106
100       3        hat-polar explorer               105
101       3        stetson                          105
```

I am trying to update the QITEM with the purchases/sales from QDEL.
the purchases are when SPL=102 or 105. so you will add quantity whrn 
spl = 102, or 105. Then you will subtract quantity when spl = anything else.
You are adding or subtracting the amount in DELQTY from QDEL, and putting it in QTYONHAND in QITEM.
I cant get my code to work. I am using Oracle Developer btw.

```
update QITEM i
set i.QtyOnHand = (select case when x.SPLNO = 101 then i.QtyOnHand -        x.DELQTY
                      when x.SPLNO = 102 then i.QtyOnHand + x.DELQTY
                      when x.SPLNO = 103 then i.QtyOnHand - x.DELQTY
                      when x.SPLNO = 104 then i.QtyOnHand - x.DELQTY
                      when x.SPLNO = 105 then i.QtyOnHand + x.DELQTY
                          else i.QtyOnHand - x.DELQTY end
                from QDEL x
               where x.ITEMNAME = i.ITEMNAME);
```

I am getting an error saying single row subquery returns more than one row. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your subquery does one calculation for each row in QDEL and returns one result per row. You want a SUM(....) where in parentheses you have the CASE expression. For more help, please edit your post and keep just the tag for your database (unless you use both SQL Server and Oracle at the same time).

Comment: so I will need case(sum(case.....))?

Comment: I removed the `sql server` tag, I don't think that was intentional, as you are clear about this being an Oracle database.

Comment: and how would I sum up only certain rows? I would have to do a sum of each type of item in the QDEL table.

Comment: Oh I just got what you meant about the tag. thanks. Im new with this site

Answer (score 0):

For every row in `QITEM`, your subquery needs to return a ***single*** value to update the `QtyOnHand` column.  Your subquery currently returns multiple values for a given `itemname`.  Maybe you were somehow expecting that it would magically perform a loop of some sorts for you, but it doesn't work that way.

As suggested in the comments, you'll need to use the `sum` aggregate function to ensure you get a single value from the subquery. Here is one way to do it:

```
update qitem i
   set i.QtyOnHand = 
           i.QtyOnHand + (select coalesce(sum(x.delqty * case when x.splno in (102, 105) then 1 else -1 end), 0)
                            from qdel x
                           where x.itemname = i.itemname)
```

Comment: what is the 1 else -1 used for?

Comment: When multiplied with `delqty`, it makes the value positive or negative, which in effect, is another way of adding or subtracting the value to/from `QtyOnHand`.

Comment: And also I am still getting null values when I run it as is. Do I need to add a specific case for 101,103,104, and 106 instead of the else -1

Comment: *And also I am still getting null values when I run it as is*: Not sure what you mean here.  What null values? Where?

Comment: i am getting null values in the qtyonhand column. There are 5 of them. It doesnt say a number, just (null).

Comment: That would happen for rows in `qitem` that don't have any matching rows in `qdel`, so the `sum` returns null in that case.  I edited the answer to add a `coalesce` around the `sum` function to default the sum to 0 in that case.

Comment: You are amazing